# dynamically allocated arrays globally give different results on different inputs in c++

Tags: c++, arrays, runtime-error

here is my code

```
   #include<iostream> 
   using namespace std;

   int n,m,t,row,column,startnode,point,check,check1=0,checkpoint;
   char space;
   int **matrix=new int*[2*n];
   int **testcase=new int*[2*m];
   int **testcase1=new int*[2*m];
   int **unvisited=new int*[2*n];
   int *distanced=new int[2*n];
   int *distanced1=new int[2*n];
   int **traversed=new int*[2*n];
   int **traversed1=new int*[2*n];
   void initialize();
   void gettestcase();
   void findpath(int start,int destination);
   void print();
int main()
{
   cout<<"enter the number of testcases"<<endl;
   cin>>t;
   cout<<"the number of testcases are="<<t<<endl;
   cout<<"Enter the number of nodes  space separated by the number of edges"<<endl;
   cin >>n>>m;
   cout<<"the number of nodes are="<<n<<" and the  number of edges="<<m<<endl;
   for(int a=1;a<=n;a++)
      {
        matrix[a]=new int[2*n];
        traversed[a]=new int[2*n];
        traversed1[a]=new int[2*n];
        unvisited[a]=new int[2*n];
      }
   for(int b=1;b<=m;b++)
      {
        testcase[b]=new int[3];
        testcase1[b]=new int[3];

      }
   for(int i=1;i<t+1;i++)
   {
    for(int l=1;l<(n+1);l++)
      {
        for(int x=1;x<(n+1);x++)
           {
             traversed[l][x]=0;
             traversed1[l][x]=0;
           }
        distanced[l]=0;
        distanced1[l]=0;
      } 
   gettestcase();
   initialize();
   for(int o=1;o<(n+1);o++)
      {
        for(int p=1;p<(n+1);p++)
           {
             cout<<matrix[o][p]<<" ";
           }
         cout<<endl;
      }
   cin>>startnode;
   cout<<"the value of startnode is="<<startnode<<endl;
   for(int j=1;j<(n+1);j++)
      {
        if(j!=startnode)
          {
            point=1;
            findpath(startnode,j);
          }
      }
   print();
  }
   return 0;
}

void gettestcase()
  {
    for(int e=1; e<(m+1) ;e++)
       {
         cin>>testcase[e][1];
         cin>>testcase[e][2];
         cin>>testcase[e][3];
         cout<<"value of testcase["<<e<<"][1]="<<testcase[e][1]<<endl;
         cout<<"value of testcase["<<e<<"][2]="<<testcase[e][2]<<endl;
         cout<<"value of testcase["<<e<<"][3]="<<testcase[e][3]<<endl;
       }
   }

void initialize() 
   {
     for(int c=1; c<(n+1);c++)
        {
          for(int d=1; d<(n+1);d++)
             {
               if(c!=d)
                 {
                  matrix[c][d]=-1;
                  cout<<"matrix["<<c<<"]["<<d<<"]="<<matrix[c][d]<<endl;
                 }
               if(c==d)
                 {
                   matrix[c][d]=0;
                   cout<<"matrix["<<c<<"]["<<d<<"]="<<matrix[c][d]<<endl;
                 }
               unvisited[c][d]=1;
               cout<<"value of unvisited["<<c<<"]["<<d<<"]="<<unvisited[c][d]<<endl;
             }
        }
     for(int e=1; e<(m+1) ;e++)
        {
          cout<<testcase[e][1]<<endl;
          if((matrix[testcase[e][1]][testcase[e][2]]!=0)&&((matrix[testcase[e][1]][testcase[e][2]]==-1)||(matrix[testcase[e][1]][testcase[e][2]]>testcase[e][3])))
            {
             matrix[testcase[e][1]][testcase[e][2]]=testcase[e][3];
            }
          if((matrix[testcase[e][2]][testcase[e][1]]!=0)&&((matrix[testcase[e][2]][testcase[e][1]]==-1)||(matrix[testcase[e][2]][testcase[e][1]]>testcase[e][3])))
            {
             matrix[testcase[e][2]][testcase[e][1]]=testcase[e][3];
            }
        }
     //initializing unvisited node list
   }
void findpath(int start,int destination)
   {
     checkpoint=point;
     cout<<"inside findpath() value of start="<<start<<"value of destination="<<destination<<endl;
     if(point==1)
       {
        traversed1[destination][point]=start;
        cout<<"value of traversed1["<<destination<<"]["<<point<<"]="<<traversed1[destination][point]<<endl;
       }
     cout<<"value of traversed1["<<destination<<"]["<<point<<"]="<<traversed1[destination][point]<<endl;
     for(int h=1;h<=n;h++)
        {
          cout<<"inside for value of h="<<h<<endl;
          if((h!=start)&&(matrix[start][h]!=-1)&&(unvisited[destination][h]==1))
            {
              for(int v=1;v<=(checkpoint);v++)
                 {
                    if(traversed1[destination][v]==h)
                      {
                        cout<<"a node is being traversed again"<<endl;
                        cout<<"value of that node="<<h<<endl;
                        cout<<"it was traversed at=traversed["<<destination<<"]["<<v<<"]"<<endl;
                        check1=1;
                        cout<<"value of check1=1"<<endl;
                        break;
                      }
                 }
              if(check1==1)
                {
                    cout<<"value of h="<<h<<"iteration is skipped because it is being traversed"<<endl;
                    check1=0;
                    continue;
                }
              unvisited[destination][h]=0;
              cout<<"inside if when value of h="<<h<<endl;
              point=point+1;
              cout<<"value of point="<<point<<endl;
              traversed1[destination][point]=h;
              cout<<"value of traversed1["<<destination<<"]["<<point<<"]="<<traversed1[destination][point]<<endl;
              cout<<"value of distanced1["<<destination<<"]="<<distanced1[destination]<<endl;
              cout<<"value of distanced1["<<destination<<"]="<<distanced1[destination]<<"+"<<matrix[start][h]<<endl;
              distanced1[destination]=distanced1[destination]+matrix[start][h];
              if(h==destination)
                {
                  cout<<"inside if where "<<h<<"==destination"<<endl;
                  if((distanced1[h]<distanced[h])||distanced[h]==0)
                    {
                      cout<<"inside if where (distanced1["<<h<<"]<distanced["<<h<<"])||(distanced["<<h<<"]==0)"<<endl;
                      distanced[h]=distanced1[h];
                      cout<<"value of distanced["<<h<<"]="<<distanced[h]<<endl;
                      for(int i=1;i<=h;i++)
                         {
                           traversed[destination][i]=traversed1[destination][i];
                           cout<<"value of traversed["<<destination<<"]["<<i<<"]="<<traversed[destination][i]<<endl;
                         }
                    }
                  break;
                }
              cout<<"calling findpath("<<h<<","<<destination<<")"<<endl;
              findpath(h,destination);
            }
          if(h==n)
            {
              cout<<"inside h==n"<<endl;
              for(int q=2;q<=n;q++)
                 {
                   if(traversed1[destination][q]>0)
                     {
                       cout<<"the node that was traversed when q="<<q<<"is="<<traversed1[destination][q]<<endl;
                       unvisited[destination][traversed1[destination][q]]=1;
                     }
                   traversed1[destination][q]=0;
                   distanced1[destination]=0;
                   point=1;
                   cout<<"value of traversed1["<<destination<<"]["<<q<<"]="<<traversed1[destination][q]<<endl;
                   cout<<"value of distanced1"<<"["<<q<<"]="<<distanced1[q]<<endl;
                   cout<<"value of point="<<point<<endl;
                 }
            }
        }
   }
     void print()
       {
         for(int k=1;k<(n+1);k++)
            {
              if(k!=startnode)
                {
                  cout<<distanced[k]<<" ";
                }
            }
         cout<<endl;
        }
        for input:-
         1
         4 4
         1 2 24
         1 4 20
         3 1 3
         4 3 12
         1
         I get correct answer which is 24 3 15 and most importantly the            code runs but for input
         1
         5 6
         1 2 5
         1 4 5
         3 1 2
         2 3 1
         2 5 3
         4 5 4
         1
```

i get segmentation fault and as you can see it will not be able to print unvisited[5][1]
even if it is globally defined on the heap it is in bounds then why segmentation fault occurs please someone help me out and explain the why segmentation fault occured.

Comment: Can you post more code to make it harder to find what the problem is? You already left off any information on where the segmentation fault happens to keep the challenge at a decent level.

Comment: Just in case this is code based on things being thought in a course: drop this course! Any teacher teaching this style of programming does more harm than good!

Comment: The right tool to solve such problems is your debugger. You should step through your code line-by-line *before* asking on Stack Overflow. For more help, please read [How to debug small programs (by Eric Lippert)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). At a minimum, you should \[edit] your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example that reproduces your problem, along with the observations you made in the debugger.

Comment: ... and just to stick with my usual comment: thou shalt test every input **after** attempting the input for success and not proceed if thee input failed.

Comment: can you point out some flaws  i am willing to learn

Comment: You call that c++? It is barely C. Bad mallocs are probably the problem. Use vectors !

Comment: Only one downvote? Come on!

Comment: @VaibhavSharma: I already pointed at one flaw (unchecked inputs). Global variables shall not exist. Using unguarded memory allocations isn't the C++ way - use, e.g., `std::vector<int>`. Array indices starting at `0` was already mentioned.

Answer (score 3):

The problem most likely resulting in a crash is that the global variables are initialized to zero and used to allocate zero sized arrays (removed some of the stuff for clarity):

```
int n,m /*.../*;
int **matrix=new int*[n];
int **testcase=new int*[m];
```

Since these are global variables `n` and `m` will start out zero initialized. That is `matrix` and `testcase` point to an array of zero `int*`. Later an assumption is made that there are `n` elements.

I'd recommend using `std::vector<T>` for suitable `T`, not using **any** global variables, and, of course, I'd check **all** inputs **after** attempting reads. I didn't look thoroughly at the code but it is unlikely that the items mentioned above are a comprehensive list of problems.

Answer (score 0):

The main problem of segmentation fault is indexing. Better use array index starting from zero or allocate a extra space if you are using from 1.

For example look into your function `intialize()`.

Your original matrix of size `nXn` but you are treating this as `(n+1)x(n+1)`

```
void initialize() 
   {
     for(int c=1; c<(n+1);c++)
        {
          for(int d=1; d<(n+1);d++)
             {
               if(c!=d)
                 {
                  matrix[c][d]=-1; // This way matrix size should be (n+1)x(n+1). 
                  cout<<"matrix["<<c<<"]["<<d<<"]="<<matrix[c][d]<<endl;
                 }
               if(c==d)
                 {
                   matrix[c][d]=0;
                   cout<<"matrix["<<c<<"]["<<d<<"]="<<matrix[c][d]<<endl;
                 }
               unvisited[c][d]=1;
               cout<<"value of unvisited["<<c<<"]["<<d<<"]="<<unvisited[c][d]<<endl;
             }
        }
```

And better to use `std::vector`.

Comment: even if i increase the size of the array two times it still gives runtime error for second input